# Water pump electricity

Tags: plumbing, water, water-pressure, well-pump, cistern

Where I live, the water pressure from the water utility is very low (About 8 PSI average). I am considering getting a jet pump with a 33 gallon pressure tank and a 400 gallon water tank for when there is no water at all. Electricity is a major concern because it is very expensive in my area, about $0.25 a KW. I use on average about 100 gallons of water a day.

Which type of jet pump or full setup in terms of HP and Watts would you guys recommend for my setup that would save me on electricity?

Most people around here just use a 1/2 HP well jet pump with the pressure tank and water storage tank. I've been reading much on [Cycle Stop Valves](http://www.cyclestopvalves.com/) which use a small pressure tank and Variable Frequency Drives, but that seems a little overkill.

Comment: I wish my electricity was that low! Consider that ideally the pump would only be running intermittently. You may be able to calculate the theoretical/estimate consumption of power if you take a few days and calculate the amount of time that the water is running and use that as a starting point. Then using the wattage of the pump and the duration you can come up with Kilowatt-hours, which is the typical unit of measure for electricity.

Comment: With only 100 gallons a day you could drop down to a 1/3 HP pump. This with a large Pressure tank should work well for such a low volume of water. The only difference I know of is most of the very small pumps are plastic where the larger ones are cast iron or bronze depending on how much the pump costs. Here in the U.S. we have 120V or 240V the higher voltage pumps are a little more efficient than the lower voltage ones. If you have 3 phase power these are the most efficient. I mention 3 phase because some folks in different countries have 3 phase.